# Adding javascript to wordpress functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, css, function

JavaScript(s) Are Not Loading

I found this really awesome static html/css template online and wanted to convert it to a wordpress theme but after the conversion i noticed the html/css is loading from inspect element view, although (visually) only the menu, section backgrounds and footer are showing on the screen while the remaining body content seems to be hiding.

Check my functions.php for any errors enqueuing the javascript. The alert works but the other scripts seem to not load. I'm sure i made a rookie mistake and coded this incorrectly.

Im developing on xampp.

Download the project files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ty9-LsirC6cPA2y-TuirC2IDpEYPOOug

```
function theme_scripts() 
{

    wp_enqueue_script( 'aos', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/aos.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'alert', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/alert.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-datepicker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-map', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/google-map.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.animateNumber.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.easing.1.3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.magnific-popup.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.stellar.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.stellar.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.waypoints.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-3.2.1.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl.carousel.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollax.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scrollax.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts', 50, 0 );
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To load the JS files, you need to:

- Go to `footer.php`
- Delete all the hardcoded scripts from the bottom (the template tries to load these, not the ones from your functions.php)

```
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/aos.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrollax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="js/google-map.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Then add this:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

This is the Wordpress footer, that invokes the hook that your `wp_enqueue()` uses for injecting the script tags (it's like `wp_head()` only for the footer). I suggest you also include the Google Maps script in your `functions.php` - keep all your external scripts in one place.

It seems that the problem is that you copied the HTML template as a Wordpress theme. They have differences, although not too big - this is one. :)

This will be the same with the missing images: the directory structure of the HTML template is not the same as of the Wordpress installation. You just have to correct that, and everything will be fine.

Comment: Hey thanks for spotting that for me! I removed the scripts from footer.php and added the hook in its place. I also included the Google Maps script into the functions.php although im still getting the same result. I really do treasure any further advice you can offer on this. And thanks again!

Comment: On MAMP the JS loaded correctly after this modification - some error messages remained, mostly from missing images. Are you sure that the page isn’t loaded from cache, so your modified template is loaded? Try in another browser or at least in incognito mode, and watch the console.

Comment: If you check the console, you’ll see the URL WP tries to load - your JS files should be loaded from **wp-contents/themes/theme_name/js** (or maybe not plural, just wp-content and theme). If it’s not the URI you see, then there’s a problem - probably caching.

Comment: If nothing seems to work, I would start anew with a blank theme: index.php, functions.php and style.css, and add back theme elements step by step. The simplest index.php would only have html, head and body tags in it (empty), then wp-footer() would be the next step and 1 (one) script from the list in functions.php. I’d do it until the error came - then I would be closer to solving the problem (or you could even start with a new WP install, and then add this blank template - that has to work)

Comment: I completely reformatted my functions.php (i was registering and enqueuing the JS and CSS incorrectly) I was also careful to arrange them using the same ordering as the original HTML template. Although some of the body content is now finally loading, not all is. any further advice you can offer is appreciated ....You may find the updated theme in the google drive folder. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Asher Sorry, but it’s quite late here - I can only have a look at it tomorrow. So, just to clarify: 1. you want the HTML template to be your Wordpress theme 2. The HTML template has ALL the necessary resources to be a Wordpress theme (js, css, images, etc)?

Comment: I added another answer after looking at the most recent version of your WP theme.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'aos', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/aos.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, false);
```

use this

```
wp_register_script( 'aos', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/aos.js', array () , 1, 1, 1);
    wp_enqueue_script ('aos');
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with the theme in your **wordpress theme updated june 20 2019** zip:

1. Modify **index.php** and **frontpage.php**

change: `"/images/` to `"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/`

change: `url(/images/` to `url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/`

change: `url('/images/` to `url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/`

suggestion: use `url('...')` instead of `url(...)` (this way you'll be sure that it's treated like a string), but at least only use one syntax in one theme. It's easier to manage, if you create a convention for your template, and stick to that.

2. Modify **functions.php**

not found: `wp-content/themes/eLeadWorks/js/jquery.timepicker.min.js` (the file is not in that library, so I commented register and enqueue out)

not found: `wp-content/themes/eLeadWorks/js/example.js` (the file is not in that library, so I commented register and enqueue out)

deregister script: `wp_deregister_script('jquery-migrate');` (place it before `wp_register_('jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min', ...)`

rename script handles (suggestion): don't use version numbers in script registering handles. This way you'll not be able to freely update versions if you need to. (so `jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min` is not OK, `jquery-migrate` is OK)

change: `wp_register_style( 'fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,400,,500,600,700', array(), 1.1, 'all' );` to `wp_register_style( 'fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,400,,500,600,700', array(), 1.1, 'all' );` (no **get_template_directory_uri()** is needed)

change: `wp_register_script( 'google-api', get_template_directory_uri() . 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false', array () , 1, 1, 1);` to `wp_register_script( 'google-api', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false', array () , 1, 1, 1);` (no **get_template_directory_uri()** is needed)

### **After these modifications**

After these changes I only see one (1) error when loading the page: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null`. This error is thrown by your Google Maps code.

**The error comes from that you don't have a DOM element with `id="map"`.**

So, **either add an element with `id="map"` (where Google Maps can place the map), or modify your code to check for `mapElement`'s value** (in google-map.js):

```
// Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map
// We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

// check if mapElement exists (not null)
if (mapElement) {
  // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

  var addresses = ['New York'];

  for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
      $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
          var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
          new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map,
              icon: 'images/loc.png'
          });

      });
  }
}
```

**After all these modifications I don't see a single error in my console.**